# How to print the data which is coming from the edittext?

Tags: android

```
final ViewGroup layout6 = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(
                           Menus.this).inflate(
                           R.layout.beefkabobsandwhichdialog, null);

AlertDialog.Builder builder6 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Menus.this);

builder6.setView(layout6);

builder6.setView(LayoutInflater.from(Menus.this).inflate(
        R.layout.beefkabobsandwhichdialog, null));

builder6.setPositiveButton("Add2Order",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                validate(((EditText) layout6
                .findViewById(R.id.quantityedittext1))
                .getText().toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: validate(String str){ log("settings ",str)}

Comment: Please fix your code and tell us what you need.

Comment: i want to print the editText data....but i m unable to print???

Comment: Do you always answer a question with a question??? (And what does "did u get me???" mean?)

Comment: Sorry, i posted my code,can u please help me???

Answer (score 0):

Your dialog's content is not set with layout6. You have a second `builder6.setView()` in there.  That is why Android cannot find the `EditText`'s ID. Also, maybe you can have more descriptive variable names. :)

Comment: actually i m getting data..but it is printing null