# How to print EditText content to the log?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to print the data which is coming from the edittext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167703/how-to-print-the-data-which-is-coming-from-the-edittext)

```
final ViewGroup layout6 = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(Menus.this)
    .inflate(R.layout.beefkabobsandwhichdialog, null);

AlertDialog.Builder builder6 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Menus.this);
builder6.setView(
    LayoutInflater.from(Menus.this)
        .inflate(R.layout.beefkabobsandwhichdialog, null));
builder6.setPositiveButton("Add2Order",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        String str = ((EditText)layout6.findViewById(R.id.quantityedittext1))
            .getText().toString();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why hello again. You just asked this question, didn't you? Have a downvote and a good day.

Comment: but i m unable to print str value in logcat...y??

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167703/how-to-print-the-data-which-is-coming-from-the-edittext

Answer (score 1):

What you have written there will print your result out in Logcat but it will be hard to see. There are two things you could try:

Replace

```
System.out.println(str);
```

with

```
System.out.println("****************************************************");
System.out.println(str);       
System.out.println("****************************************************");
```

It will be hard to miss that.

What people usually do though, is print out in Logcat format. Here's the code on how to do it:

```
Log.i(tag, str);
```

'tag' here is a string and it will show in a left-hand column in Logcat. This makes it extremely easy to identify as you can add a filter to just show the log with your selected tag. This is the recommended way to do it, but you can use the standard System.out.println(). It does work, just really hard to see.

Comment: Please use the log.i(tag, str); format for any android projects.  This is the standard and will make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: I don't understand, was this directed at me or rajesh?